# How can I know if a value of a cell has changed without losing the focus in DataGridView

Tags: vb.net, winforms, validation, datagridview

I'm validating the cells of a `DataGridView` and I want that if you change the value without change to the other cell output a message.

Comment: is it using wpf or winforms?

Comment: Your question is rather unclear but I suspect that you need to handle the `CellValidating` event. Just like the `Validating` event of a control, it allows you to validate the contents and prevent focus shifting if it fails.

Comment: @YairMaron, a Data Greed View, more commonly known as a `DataGridView`, is specific to WinForms.

Comment: @jmcilhinney I have the CellValidating event but if I change the value of a cell and delete the value without changing the cell and then change the cell, I need a message output that says that the cell cannot be empty

Comment: Firstly, that comment makes little to no sense. Secondly, no one should have to read the comments to understand the question. That's what the question is for. Edit your question and provide the FULL and CLEAR explanation that you should have in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need the CellLeave event. [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellleave?view=net-5.0)

```vb
Private Sub dataGridView1_CellLeave(ByVal sender As Object, _
    ByVal e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) _
    Handles dataGridView1.CellLeave

    If (String.IsNullOrEmpty(dataGridView1(e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex).Value)) Then
        MessageBox.Show("Error", "Cell Empty!")
    End If

End Sub
```

Also, there I think there is not a considerable advantage of validating before it loses focus because it is gonna lose focus anyways while any other operation is performed. (Not quite used to VB.net correct me if I am wrong)

Comment: `CellValidating` event would be useful in this case as @jmcilhinney mentioned, it has a `Cancel` property which you can set to `True` which would prevent the user from leaving the cell. `there is not a considerable advantage of validating before it loses focus` sure there is, maybe you need the user to fix the issue before continuing? Maybe you need that value that is used in another routine? Otherwise you'd have to go through the validating check again and or keep track of all this.